# Available framework version for AWS SageMaker SKLearn

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker Python SDK's SKLearn class which has a parameter called framework version. Its default is 0.20.0.
I want to use a different version of Scikit-learn (0.21.0 or higher). It is possible? How do I know which versions are supported?

Answer (score 3):

I actually couldn't find a nice link that showed this, but if you enter an incorrect framework the error message will print out the available versions.

```py
estimator = SKLearn(
    entry_point = "train.py",
    source_dir = source_dir,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    role = role,
    framework_version='0.30.0',
    py_version = 'py3'
)

ValueError: Unsupported sklearn version: 0.30.0. You may need to upgrade your SDK version (pip install -U sagemaker) for newer sklearn versions. 
Supported sklearn version(s): 0.20.0, 0.23-1.
```